# Ubuntu 15.04 Second monitor detected but cannot enable it on one account only

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, 15.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my new computer and connected a second monitor to it. When I log as the first user created on the computer it works fine, but with an other user, the monitor doesn't receive any signal.

In the system settings, the screen is detected but left disabled. When I try to enable it, the monitor seems to receive a signal, but then it instantly goes black again and it isn't detected anymore.

I looked up several similar posts but none of them seem to be linked to a specific account... I tried this workaround which didn't work ([External monitor recognized but getting "no signal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234153/external-monitor-recognized-but-getting-no-signal)).

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6736 x 2572, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080      60.1*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x576i       50.1  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   720x480i       60.1     60.1  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

[edit] I just noticed, the "current" display size is very strange. Right now it gives me "3840 x 1080", it seems to change when I try to activate the HDMI display.

Comment: I tried:
xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto => the screen wakes up only to display again, "No signal".
The, disper -e => same thing.

The weird thing is, when I do either one of those commands (or manually try to activate the monitor in the System Settings), and do a screenshot, the screen appears twice as big as my primary monitor (the other half, to the right, is black)...

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing the SUPER key at the same time as you press the letter P.

The SUPER button is the Windows key, usually right next to Alt or space bar. Good luck.

Comment: This only works on Windows.

Comment: @NonnyMoose There are laptops out there that have a physical button for video output switching hardcoded to the Super+P keyboard combination.